# iOS writeToURL delay or screen freeze, how to resolve the thread in the case

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a complex operation, then when the operate complete,

It will save to NSData write to the file to preview.

I encounter a problem, when I click the button ,

the button action will start show MBProgress thing and async to complex operate in background.

When the file write success, It will go to prepareForSegue method pass value to destinationViewController.

I try to add thread, But I found my screen always freeze  or can't write file success for stay this screen show the alert(I think it is operate is not complete, so get the BOOL is NO).

How to write the resolve in this case for show the MBProgress wait the operation complete , then navigation to next viewcontroller?

Thank you very much.

My Code below:

```
 - (IBAction)fileBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender{

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    [self doComplexOperateAction];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        fileHud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        fileHud.label.text = @"file operating....";
        fileHud.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        });
    });

 }

 - (void) doComplexOperateAction{

       ....... do something.......

      NSError *error;
writeFileSuccess = [resultFilie.fileContent writeToURL:previewFileUrl
                                                         options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete
                                                             error:&error];
 }

 -(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{

 if( [identifier isEqualToString:@"fileSuccessSegue"] ){        
         if( writeFileSuccess == YES ){
            fileHud.hidden = YES;
            fileHud = nil;
             return YES;
         }else{
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          msgAlertController.message = @"can't write file success";
          [self presentViewController:msgAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            fileHud.hidden = YES;
            fileHud = nil;
        });
        return NO;
    }
}
   return NO;
 }

 -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

 if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fileSuccessSegue"] ){

     .........
     NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileTmpPathString];
     fileSuccessViewController *pfVC = [segue destinationViewController];
     pfVC.filePathURL = fileURL;

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand if the file was written or no. Anyway, keep in mind that if you try to dispatch to main thread you should always first check if you are already on the main thread, because it can hang the application.
Example:

```
if([NSThread isMainThread]){
   //perform gui operation
} else {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //perfrom gui operation
   });
}
```

Edit: You should consider using dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_async for the main thread, since you have nested dispatches in - (IBAction)fileBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender:

```
    [self doComplexOperateAction];

    dispatch_**sync**(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        fileHud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        fileHud.label.text = @"file operating....";
        fileHud.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        });
    });
```

Comment: My code will do something operate and save the file. when the file save success, it will navigation to next uiviewcontroller. So I want to wait the file save complete, then code will run prepareforsegue method navigation next controller. But I don't know how to wait the file save complete navigation to next viewcontroller. thank you .

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank your response. I try to using dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_asaync for main thread, But the "writeFileSuccess" value  is NO, not wait save file complete then go to the prepareforsegue.

Comment: I noticed you use DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND. If you dispatch to queue with this priority, everything in dispatch block is executed as in background. This can cause problem as the file you write to maybe isn't background writable. The file must have special attributes in order to be background writable. So you can either change the queue or ensure the file is background writable.

Comment: Milan Markovic are you sure you don't have error when writeFile? What value in error?

Answer (score 0):

I think It will be something like this:

```
@property (noatomic) BOOL uploading;
- (IBAction)fileBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender{

    fileHud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    fileHud.label.text = @"file operating....";
    fileHud.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [self doComplexOperateAction];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fileSuccessSegue" sender:nil];
        });
    });

}

- (void) doComplexOperateAction{
    self.uploading = YES;
    ....... do something.......

    NSError *error;
    writeFileSuccess = [resultFilie.fileContent writeToURL:previewFileUrl
                                                     options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete
                                                         error:&error];

    self.uploading = NO;
}

-(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{

    if( [identifier isEqualToString:@"fileSuccessSegue"] ){        
        if( writeFileSuccess == YES ){
            fileHud.hidden = YES;
            fileHud = nil;
            return YES;
        }else{
            msgAlertController.message = @"can't write file success";
            [self presentViewController:msgAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            fileHud.hidden = YES;
            fileHud = nil;
        });
        return NO;
        }
    }
    return !self.uploading;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fileSuccessSegue"] ){

        .........
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileTmpPathString];
        fileSuccessViewController *pfVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        pfVC.filePathURL = fileURL;

    }
}
```

I would advise you to rewrite this code. I do not like how you handle errors. Because **writeFileSuccess** have unsuspected value while you uploading content.

Comment: thank you response first. I try you fixed  code will show alert not wait the file save complete. I need wait the file save success then pass the url path to next uiviewcontroller. thanks.

Comment: May be I don't understand what you need. My code will show MBProgressHUD while save file. After file have saved it will perform segue to show other viewcontroller.

Comment: Hi Sergey, the meaning is you are right. But i try to using your method, it will crash.@@it show [... fileBtnAction:]_block_invoke

Comment: Can you provide crash message?

Comment: I trace the log, writeFileSuccess is show 1, then crash. the crash just jump to (lldb) , not show exception message. debug navigator show
Thread 1 Queue:com.apple.root.background-qos(concurrent)
_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow
[MyViewcontroller fileBtnAction:]_block_invoke
...@@

Comment: Can you share all code? What you do in decrypteAction?

Comment: I find the crash line, is "" dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });""" in below block dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIOR‌​ITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ [self doComplexOperateAction]; // write here will crash.. }); If I comment these code, I can't see the MBProgress show and still freeze on the screen. I have to wait some time then navigation to other viewcontroller.@@   sorry, I have replace some function name, I was not change. decrypteAction is doComplexOperateAction.  I still got crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136233/discussion-between-dickfala-and-sergey).